# Operations on étale sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, etale-covers

Which of the following operations on étale sheaves $A$ commute with tensor powers? (eg. for instance $i^*(A^{\otimes n})=(i^*(A))^{\otimes n}$?)

- $i^*(A)$, $i$ closed immersion.
- $i_*(A)$
- $i^!(A)$
- $i_!(A)$
- $j^*(A)$, $j$ open immersion.
- $j_!(A)$

Comment: All standard pullbacks are symmetric monoidals (so in particular they commute with tensor powers). See the [six operations formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_operations) for more details (be warned that a lot of these operations are better behaved if derived)

Comment: $i_*$ and $j_!$ also commute with nonempty tensor products, since they are the kernels of $j^*$ and $i^*$.